# Joomla 2.5 with Sobi Pro and Mandarin characters

Tags: joomla, sobipro

My client has a single page on his Joomla! 2.5 site whose content must be translated into Mandarin. In text areas within Sobi Pro, we can easily add the Mandarin text, and all is fine, but in text fields, we are unable to add the text - we get a bright red validation error with the text "The data entered in the "area name" field contains not allowed characters".

How can I make it work so that I can enter Chinese characters in these text fields?

Thanks!

Kobus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by means of a person on the Sobi Pro website; it was a filter that prevented input of the characters. Problem is solved.

Thanks!

Kobus